# Read RFID by Android device

Tags: android

I need to read RFID tag and use it as a bar-code system. How to read RFID by using an Android device? Please guide me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This topic is too big to be addressed here. Here is a [presentation](http://todbot.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/nfc_rfid_on_android_todekurt_where20.pdf) that can get you started.

NFC is a type of RFID and I *think* that is what you actually want to know about. Since some Android devices [support NFC](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=49L7z3rxz4Q).

Answer (score 1):

I was also going through the R&D process that how to read **RFID tags** on Android, So I found some useful links which describes how exactly it works.

For basics understanding go [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc.html#tag-dispatch) & for [demo Application](http://www.codexpedia.com/android/android-nfc-read-and-write-example/) it has very good explanation